# Why does setting the condition of an variable to be undefined give an error?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, variables

I want the function to run only once on the first click and no more. But I get an error that `someVar` is not defined, that is what I have included in the condition. Why is it giving the error? How to solve this?

```
button.onclick = function () {
  if (someVar == undefined) {
    console.log("Hi");
    someVar = 1; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Add this `let someVar;` above `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the someVar as a global Variable?
use it like this =>

```
var someVar = undefined;
button.onclick = function () {
  if (this.someVar == undefined) {
    console.log("Hi");
    this.someVar = 1; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it that the variable is undefined already?

Comment: If you are using `this`, you don't even need to define someVar. What even more in this case `this.someVar` and `someVar` are two different variables, `someVar` will always be `undefined` and not used in this case...

Comment: @ulou No, if you declare a variable globally it will become a property of the global object `window`, and in even handlers `this ` is also window so it will be the same variable.

Comment: No it won't, unless you will `bind` `this` to `onClick` `function`.

Comment: Try it. If unbound `this` will be `window`

Comment: @mousetail Here you are: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-forked-50o8e?file=/index.js

Comment: The sandbox is throwing errors for me, but you can easily verify this by copying this into your browser: `var t = 10; document.addEventListener('click', ()=>console.log(this.t));`

Comment: @ulou Seems like this is a difference between `addEventListener` and assigning directly to `onclick`. So you are correct

Comment: It's up to declaration, if you will use `function` in callback, then `this` references to `function`, but you can use arrow function `() => {...}`, then `this` will reference to block above.

Answer (score 2):

`this` approach (`this` references to `onClick` `function`):

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.onclick = function () {
  if (this.someVar == undefined) {
    console.log("Hi");
    this.someVar = 1; 
  }
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```

Global variable approach:

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button')

let someVar = undefined;

button.onclick = function () {
  if (someVar == undefined) {
    console.log("Hi")
    someVar = 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
```